# Mostrar array en react.js

Tags: reactjs

Bueno estoy en la vista y traigo un array por una ruta de laravel que me retorna un array.

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('http://localhost:8000/noticias')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ destacada: response.data});
      console.log(this.state.destacada[0].titulo);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Esta es la función de la vista. En la que /noticias me devuelve 1 array. Si lo muestro por consola me lo muestra espectacular. La cuestión es cuando quiero mostrarlo en el render no me funciona.

```
<div className="titulo-noticia">{this.state.destacada[0].titulo}</div>
```

La consola me dice:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'titulo' of undefined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

te recomiendo primero sacar esa función del `componentDidMount()` porque eso se ejecuta después del render, segundo cada vez que haces cambio a un `state` que el render esté utilizando, el render se vuelve a ejecutar automáticamente, pero parece ser que this.state no está definido. Te doy dos soluciones:

- Solución 1

Usar NEXT.JS que es una librería muy buena para lo que necesitas además de que básicamente puedes olvidarte del webpack, gracias a next tienes un nuevo método llamado `getInitialProps` lo que te permite básicamente, crear un `props` de esta manera

```
static async getInitialProps(){    
  let res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/noticias')
  let data = await res.json();
  return {data}
}
```

Gracias a esto tendrás lo que necesitas directamente en los `props` así:

```
render(){
  return(
   <div className="titulo-noticia">{this.props.data.destacada[0].titulo}</div>
  )}
```

- Solución 2

Puedes crear una función y ejecutarla en el `componentWillMount` así:

```
getData=()=>{
   fetch ('http://localhost:8000/noticias')
   .then(res=>{      
     return res.json() 
   })  
   .then(data=>{
     this.setState({data:data})
   })
}
componentWillMount(){
   this.getData()
}
```

Pero eso sí, debes definir los states que uses, para hacerlo tienes que hacer esto

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {};
 //En "this.state" debes definir todo lo que vayas a usar, por ejemplo la varaiable 
 //"destacada" debeía ir como this.state= {destacada: []}
}
```

Y por último, es probable que esto ya lo sepas pero a lo mejor no, para hacer render de todos los elementos de un array simplemente debes hacer una función "map" así;

```
render(){
  return(
    {
       this.state.detacada.map((element)=>{
         <div className="titulo-noticia">{element}</div>
       })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: [componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#legacy-lifecycle-methods) está deprecada y **no se debe utilizar ya que se removerá en la versión 17 de React**

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount()` se ejecuta después del primer `render()` del elemento, y `setState()` lo que hace es ejecutar otro `render()`

Fíjate en esta gráfica:

> [image: React Lifecycle]
>   Tomado de: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Y aquí un ejemplo práctico de como y cuando se llama cada método

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Hola'
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('did mount: ', Date.now());
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({name: 'Adios'}), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render: ', Date.now());
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {this.state.name}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

#### Tu problema

Al tu querer utilizar `this.state.destacada[0].titulo` el método `render` ya se ejecutó pero en el `state` la variable todavía no existe. De hecho si no se ha declarado en el constructor, `this.state` no existe

#### Posibles soluciones

Podrías o bien asignar un valor por defecto en el `constructor` en el componente, o validar que la variable exista, por ejemplo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({greeting: [{message: 'Hola :D'}]}), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Esperalo...</p>
        <p>
          {this.state.greeting ? this.state.greeting[0].message : ''}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```